# Fetching data from api as json, but html nesting is off

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to nest an `<a>` tag within my `<li>` tag when looping through some JSON data, but it isn't:

```
var ul = $('<ul/>');
$.each(data.headlines, function() {
var linkFromJson = "<a>" + this.headline + "</a>";
linkFromJson = $(linkFromJson).attr("href", this.links.web.href).attr("target", "_blank");
var listItem = document.createElement('li');
ul.append(listItem, linkFromJson);
});
// append this list to the document body
$('body').append(ul);
```

What i get is a `<li></li>` and the `<a>` tag follows, but it displays the hyperlink correctly. When I write the code out to nest the json, it gives me `[object][Object]` back after it loops through the items for each `<li>` tag.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: I figured it out, using `.html` to insert the built link inside the `<li>`, and them append the `<li>`s into the `<ul>`:

```
var ul = $('<ul/>');
$.each(data.headlines, function() {
var linkFromJson = "<a>" + this.headline + "</a>";
linkFromJson = $(linkFromJson).attr("href", this.links.web.href).attr("target", "_blank");
var listItem = $('<li/>');
$(listItem).html(linkFromJson);
ul.append(listItem);
});
// append this list to the document body
$('body').append(ul);
},
error: function() {
// handle the error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), `ul.append(listItem, linkFromJson)` inserts all content to the end of the `ul` element sequentially. It will not nest the given content inside each other.

To achieve that, you must first append `<a>` to `<li>` and then append the resulting `<li>` to `<ul>`

```
var listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.append(linkFromJson);
ul.append(listItem);
```

Comment: Thank you Olaf. I used your answer as a basis for the solution.